# TypeScript - defintion/interface for object that is not an array

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, tsc

I am tussling with this feature of JS/JSON.stringify:

```
const v = [];
v.foo = 5;
v.start = true;
console.log(JSON.stringify({value: v}));
```

you will get this in the console:

```
{"value":[]}
```

so I want to create type is an object but not an array:

```
export const acceptsObjectsButNotArrays = function(v: MyType){
  v[marker] = true;
  console.log(JSON.stringify({value:v});
}
```

using TS, is there a defintion I can use for MyType, that can ensure it's an object but not an array?

```
export interface ObjectButNotArray extends Object {
  [key:string]: any
}
```

it needs to have an index signature, like above, so I can add arbitrary properties to it.

The closest thing, I can think of would be:

```
export type ObjectButNotArray = object & !Array<any>
```

although that syntax is bogus.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are objects, so basically we want a derived type not to be allowd where a base type is require, which in OOP terms is not really ok.

You can't define such a type directly, but you can use conditional type to ensure your function does not accept an array as an argument by creating an incompatibility if an array is passed in. If the parameter is an array we impose an extra restriction on the parameter that essentially makes the parameter impossible (or at least improbable) to pass in.

```
export const acceptsObjectsButNotArrays = function <T extends { [n: string]: any }>(v: T & ErrorIfArray<T>) {
    v["marker"] = true;
    console.log(JSON.stringify({ value: v }));
}

type ErrorIfArray<T> = T extends any[] ? "Argument must be an array" : T;

acceptsObjectsButNotArrays({ // ok
    a: ""
});
acceptsObjectsButNotArrays([]); // Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type '"Argument must be an array"'.
```